# Find array values in C# DataFrame (equivalent to .isin in Python)?

Tags: python, c#, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert a well-working Python scripts into C#.

I have a C# DataFrame, using `Microsoft.Data.Analysis;` library.
Column names are [time] , [site], [samples], [temperature]

I need to process two sequential tasks:

1. Group rows with same [time] AND [site] --> sum the values in [sample] and keep only 1 value for [temperature] column, last one.
   In Python (Pandas) I have done this:

   `dF_out= df_in.groupby(['time','site'], as_index=False).agg({'sample':'sum', 'temperature':'last'})`
2. Find matching values of [sample] with ANY (ALL !) of the values in a constant array of integers, in Python I've done the following:

   `df_out= df_out.loc[df_out['samples'].isin(int_array)]`

In Python, which I am more confident with, methods `.GrouBy(...)` `.isin(...)` methods are straightforward and very well described in Pandas docs. Can anyone help me converting this in C# in the most efficient way ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Access row values via [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers) to group then by time and site.
2. Assuming second task follows the first one, you can perform both in a single `Select()` operation:

- Sum the samples from local grouping, save it as `SamplesSum`. In order to sum it, you'll need to cast in to appropriate type, I used `int` as an example.
- Get last temperature from last grouping entry, save it as `LastTemperature`
- Lastly, create an intersection of two collections (`int_array` and local grouping of samples), save it as `MatchingValues`. Here too, don't forget about proper casting when selecting sample value from a data frame row

I'm a bit worried about selecting last temperature without sorting it first. The last one will be simply the last one from the grouping, without the certainty that it will be the smallest one or highest value.

```cs
var int_array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var dF_out = df_in.Rows
    .GroupBy(row => new { Time = row[0], Site = row[1] })
    .Select(group => new
    {
        SamplesSum = group.Sum(row => (int)row[2]),
        LastTemperature = group.Last()[3],
        MatchingValues = int_array.Intersect(group.Select(row => (int)row[2])),
    });
```

Resulting `dF_out` collection will have such structure:

```
[
   {
      "SamplesSum":25,
      "LastTemperature":28.0,
      "MatchingValues":[
         21,
         4
      ]
   },
   {
      "SamplesSum":3,
      "LastTemperature":27.0,
      "MatchingValues":[
         3
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: thank you for your uselful insight. As mentioned I have little experience in C# Data Analysis. I have question about your code. 

`.GroupBy(row => new { Time = row[0], Site = row[1] })`  , is **row[n]** correct to use here ? [_Time_]  and [_Site_] are columns, and records are stored in rows. Shouldn't I select columns ? . As per your concern about "last" value, records are stored in descending chronological order, hence "last" value is actually the lower row in a group. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I went through a similar task so i can report a possible solution for other readers:

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Data.Analysis;

// Assume that df_in is a DataFrame with columns [time], [site], [samples], and [temperature]

var df_out = df_in.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => new { Time = row.Field<DateTime>("time"), Site = row.Field<string>("site") })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Time = g.Key.Time,
        Site = g.Key.Site,
        Samples = g.Sum(row => row.Field<int>("samples")),
        Temperature = g.Last().Field<float>("temperature")
    })
    .ToDataFrame();
```

then for the second task,

```
using System.Linq;

// Assume that df_out is a DataFrame with a column [samples] and int_array is an array of integers

var filtered_df = df_out.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => int_array.Any(i => i == row.Field<int>("samples")))
    .ToDataFrame();
```